# setInterval NodeJS is adding additional time

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why is the native `setInterval` function adding 1 milliseconds after *~each* new function call, which will be triggered by the interval?

This the log I get after I pinged the API for at least 20 times:

```
2017-09-10T12:42:56.568Z INFO: Pinging API
2017-09-10T12:42:58.569Z INFO: Pinging API
2017-09-10T12:43:00.569Z INFO: Pinging API
2017-09-10T12:43:02.570Z INFO: Pinging API
2017-09-10T12:43:04.570Z INFO: Pinging API
2017-09-10T12:43:06.571Z INFO: Pinging API
2017-09-10T12:43:08.571Z INFO: Pinging API
2017-09-10T12:43:10.571Z INFO: Pinging API
2017-09-10T12:43:12.572Z INFO: Pinging API
2017-09-10T12:43:14.572Z INFO: Pinging API
2017-09-10T12:43:16.572Z INFO: Pinging API
2017-09-10T12:43:18.573Z INFO: Pinging API
2017-09-10T12:43:20.574Z INFO: Pinging API
2017-09-10T12:43:22.574Z INFO: Pinging API
2017-09-10T12:43:24.575Z INFO: Pinging API
2017-09-10T12:43:26.576Z INFO: Pinging API
2017-09-10T12:43:28.576Z INFO: Pinging API
2017-09-10T12:43:30.576Z INFO: Pinging API
2017-09-10T12:43:32.577Z INFO: Pinging API
2017-09-10T12:43:34.577Z INFO: Pinging API
```

Currently my code is just doing the following inside the callback function:

```
setInterval(() => {
    // this just logs the info
    logger.info('Pinging API') 
}, 2000)
```

I hope some one can explain me, when the interval is reset and why it isn't reliable on a millisecond basis (never mind the nanosecond basis)?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified

Comment: setInterval is not accurate. JS code cant be time accurate. No code running on a thread based system can be time accurate.

Comment: `In modern browsers ...` but this is about NodeJS, which isn't a browser.

Comment: @kyon google *V8* ...

Comment: Anyway, I'm just curious why it can't be? I would love to see an answer which explains this in a bit more detailed way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Some self testing:*

Take a piece of paper and write all the squares onto it, e.g. *1,4,9,16...* , then take a clock and every 10 seconds knock on the table.

When doing the first numbers its easy and you can [*multithread*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading_(computer_architecture)) (not multitask) easily. However when the math gets more complicated, you will forget about knocking and youre busy with calculating.

*How is that related to processors?*

A computer is running a few (thousand) jobs at the same time. It displays the time, changes your background image, loads updates, cleans up RAM, etc. To do this, it does *multithreading*, so it changes between jobs (threads) a few times per second. So it looks like that it does it the same time.

*What happens with timers?*

A computer has [hardwareside timers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Precision_Event_Timer).
When a timer is finished, it  [*interrupts*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt) the current proccess ( if possible!) and continues with handling the timer ( logging some stuff).

*If possible?*

Interrupting a process needs time ( switching [RAM pages](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit), cleaning up the register) and like a human can be busy with computations a computer can be too. Also [interrupting too often](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_storm) can cause a [livelock](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock#Livelock). Thats why timers are not precise as the computer awaits currently sheduled jobs until it does a [context change](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch). And to be honest: who cares about that millisecond?

Comment: Do you also have a link to a certain post/blog, where I can read more about it? thank you for answering anyway, very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` and `setTimeout` do not guarantee to execute the callback on exact time, you can read its api document in this page [setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified)